# Not getting correct output when trying to print a double in C

Tags: c, printf, double

This should be a simple fix. So I am trying to get segments of a length to print out to use as a variable in the future. The problem is that the variable will not initialize correctly. (Ignore the commented sections for that is for once I get this problem fixed)

The problem lies with this line: `double h = (1/m);`

```
int main(void) {
    int t = 1; //time
    int m = 0; //number of segments of bar
    int n = 0; //number of intervals related to time

    printf("Enter number of segments: ");
    scanf("%d", &m);
    printf("Enter number of time intervals: ");
    scanf("%d", &n);

    printf("%d", m);
    printf("\n");

    double h = (1/m); //length of bar segments
    double d = (1/n); //length of time interval

    printf("%lf", h);
    printf("\n");
    printf("%d", m);
    printf("\n");
}
```

My output:

```
Enter number of segments: 5
Enter number of time intervals: 10
5
0.000000
5
Program ended with exit code: 0
```

The correct output shouldn't be 0.00000, it should be 0.20000. I realize this is probably something I am missing but still I cannot seem to figure it out.

Answer (score 3):

```
double h = (1/m); //length of bar segments
double d = (1/n); //length of time interval
```

These operations do integer division. Try

```
double h = (1.0/m); //length of bar segments
double d = (1.0/n); //length of time interval
```

Comment: I knew it was something simple...still used to java. It worked thank you.

Comment: @Tyler. Java will _also_ truncate if you provide integer operands to `/` :-)

Answer (score 3):

Integer calculations are truncated to integer values, even when you subsequently assign them to a `double`. Think of the following:

```
double h = 1 / m;
```

as:

- do the *integer* calculation `1 / m` which, truncated, gives zero for the vast majority of `m` values.
- convert that zero to a `double` (it's still a zero) and assign it to `h`.

This is specified in the ISO standard, `C11 6.5.5 Multiplicative operators /6` (my italics):

> When integers are divided, the result of the `/` operator is the algebraic quotient *with any
>   fractional part discarded.*

What you need is:

```
double h = 1.0 / m;
double d = 1.0 / n;
```

to ensure the *calculation itself* is performed as a floating point one.